# DevIL library: save gray scale image in three matrices instead one

Tags: c++, grayscale, pgm, devil

I need to make a program that convert a RGB image to a GRAYSCALE image and save it in PGM format. I use DevIL library, but when I save the image, I obtain always a 3D image (3 matrix), in grayscale but, if I load it in MATLAB, I have 3 matrices instead of just one. How can I obtain just one matrix in my output file using DevIL?

```
 int main()
 {

  ilInit();
  ilEnable(IL_ORIGIN_SET);
  ilOriginFunc(IL_ORIGIN_UPPER_LEFT);
  ilEnable(IL_FILE_OVERWRITE);

  ILuint ImageName; // The image name to return.
  ilGenImages(1, &ImageName);
  ilBindImage(ImageName);
  if(!ilLoadImage("/home/andrea/Scrivania/tests/siftDemoV4/et000.jpg"))
  {   printf("err");
      exit;
  }
  else
    printf("caricata\n");

  ILuint width,height;
  width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
  height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
  double v[3]={0.2989360212937755001405548682669177651405334472656250000,0.5870430744511212495240215503145009279251098632812500000,0.1140209042551033058465748126764083281159400939941406250};
 printf("%.55f %.55f %.55f",v[0],v[1],v[2]);
ILubyte *imgValue=ilGetData();
int i=0;
ILubyte imgNuova[width*height];


while( i < width*height)
{


        imgNuova[i]=(char)round( ( (double)imgValue[3*i]*v[0])+ ( (double)imgValue[3*i+1]*v[1])+((double)imgValue[3*i+2]*v[2]));

        i++;

}


ILuint ImageName2;

ilGenImages(2, &ImageName2);
ilBindImage(ImageName2);
ilTexImage(width, height, 1, 1, IL_LUMINANCE,
           IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgNuova);
iluFlipImage();
ilSave(IL_PNM,"/home/andrea/Scrivania/tests/siftDemoV4/et000new.pgm");

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to a bug in the `PNM` export, DevIL can and will only write `PPM` (Portable Pixmaps, 3 channel RGB) files regardless of the file extension. The only solution to this is to use a different file format, that supports single channel grayscale images, like `PNG`.

Matlab should be able to use that just as well. If you absolutely need or want files in the `PGM` format, you will have to use a converter like `png2pnm`.